# Is there something wrong with my binary search algorithm?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I'm writing a program where you can enter a words which will get stored in an ArrayList. You can then search for these words, by entering them in a textField and pressing a button. (You can also sort them, if pressing another button). If the word is found the place in the ArrayList of the word should be printed out and if it's not found that should be printed out. I thought this worked until just recently when I tested it (it have worked before): I entered a word I knew was in the ArrayList which made it print out the position of the word in the ArrayList (which is what I want it to do). I then entered a word which I knew didn't exist in the ArrayList which made it print out that the word doesn't exist (which is also what I want it to do). But when I after that searched for a word I knew existed in the ArrayList, it printed out that the word couldn't be found. I then tried this with another word I knew existed in the ArrayList, but I couldn't find that either. I have after this restarted the program several times and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I have no idea why or why not...

The array gets sorted before I run the algorithm so I know that's not the problem...

Down below is the class with my search algorithm:

```
public class SearchAlg {

  public static String binary (ArrayList<String> list, String user) {
    int first = 0;
    int found = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int last = list.size();
    String strFound = "";

    while (first < last && found == 0) {
        middle = ((first + last) / 2);
        if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) > 0) {
            first = middle + 1;
        } else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        } else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) < 0) {
            last = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1) {
        strFound = "The word " + user + " exists on the place " + middle + " in the Arraylist";
    } else {
        strFound = "The word " + user + " does not exist in the Arraylist";
    }
    return strFound;
  }
}
```

Here is my sorting algorithm:
    public class Sort {
        static private String strTemp;
        static private int i;
        static private int n;

```
public static ArrayList bubbelSort (ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (n = 0; n < list.size() - i - 1; n++) {
        if (list.get(n).compareTo(list.get(n + 1)) > 0) {
            strTemp = list.get(n);
            list.set(n, list.get(n + 1));
            list.set(n + 1, strTemp);
        }
    }
    }
    return list;
}
```

And this is my `Main` class:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtaOutput.setText("");
    String wrd = txtfEnter.getText();
    list.add(wrd);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        txtaOutput.append(list.get(i) + "\n");
    }
}

private void btnSortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    txtaOutput.setText("");
    Sort.bubbelSort(list);
}

private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String user = txtfSearch.getText();
    txtaOutput.setText("");
    String bin = SearchAlg.binary(list, user);
    txtaOutput.append(bin);
}
```

I have no idea what's causing this, so any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I now know that the problem is that the first item in the ArrayList ins't searchable. So if the ArrayList consists of `a, b, c` for example, then only `b` and `c` are searchable. If I try and search for `a`, it says that it can't be found.

Comment: For what it's worth, you should probably capture the return value of compareTo to a local variable.  That's a potentially costly operation, so you only want to do it once per loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int first= 0;
    int last= a.length - 1;
    while (first<= last) {
        int middle = first+ (last- first) / 2;
        if      (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) < 0) last = middle - 1;
        else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) > 0) first= middle + 1;
        else {
        found =1 ;
        break;
        }
    }
```

and don't forget to sort your list as mentioned in the previous post

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: you're welcome your code was almost fine but the key is this "middle = first+ (last- first) / 2;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the very last step of your search. There is a chance you update the 'first' and 'last', and in the next iteration you would find the value, but instead you break from the loop.

Solution: remove the variable `found` entirely, and also these two lines:

```
} else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) == 0) {
        found = 1;
```

and where you now write...

```
if (found == 1) {
```

...instead do...

```
if (user.compareTo(list.get(first)) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off by one.

You initialize the method with `last = list.size()`, implying that you're searching the half open interval `[first, last>` (from and including `first`, to but excluding `last`).

However, in your loop, you set `last = middle - 1`, which would work if your search range was the closed interval `[first, last]` (from and including `first`, to and including `last`).

You should make up your mind as to whether `last` should point **on** the last element, or **after** the last element. Here's your loop if you go with the latter:

```
while (first < last && found == 0) {
    middle = ((first + last) / 2);
    if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) > 0) {
        first = middle + 1;
    } else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) == 0) {
        found = 1;
    } else if (user.compareTo(list.get(middle)) < 0) {
        last = middle;                                   // <-- Remove -1
    }
}
```